# Dynamically output Simple_form fields in a loop

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, paperclip, simple-form

I have paperclip fields attached to my model for different types of files. As an example the document type "test_doc" allows three files to be uploaded and the model fields are named "test_doc1", "test_doc2", "test_doc3". Other document types like "another_doc" that have a different number of allowed files all named with the same naming convention.

I'm trying to create a generic document upload page that gets the document type that needs to be added (stored in @document_type variable) and the max number of documents that can be uploaded for that type (stored in @max_num variable) then outputs the appropriate number of fields in the view

I would like to output fields in the following format but to do so in a loop that uses the document type and the number of documents variables. This would require changing in a few places in this code block to output the variables dynamically but I can't figure out how to do it.

I'm hoping that someone can help me convert this code into a loop that uses the two above variables to output the right number of fields.

```
<%= f.input :aou_document1, :label => false, :wrapper => :append, :class => "form-group" do %>
<label class="col-sm-3 control-label no-padding-right">
  <% if @lap.aou_document1.blank? %>
      Choose <%= @document_type %>
  <% else %>
      <%= link_to @lap.aou_document1.url do %>
          <i class="icon-file-alt"></i>
          <%= @lap.aou_document1_file_name[0..40] %>...
      <% end %>
  <% end %>
</label>
<div class="col-sm-9">
  <% if !@lap.aou_document1.blank? %><span class="pull-left"><div class="space-4"></div>Replace with</span><% end %>
  <% if !@lap.aou_document1.blank? %><div class="space-4"></div><% end %><%= f.file_field :aou_document1, :class => "col-xs-7 col-sm-5" %>
</div>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

The fields_for helper will automatically insert all of the nested fields for a parent, you shouldn't be handling it manually.

Your generic form should look something like:

```
<%= form_for @document do |f| %>
  <%= fields_for :files do |file| %>
    your code for the files goes here
```

Then in the controller you would simply build the correct number of files for each document. Or you could do it in a callback when the document is created. There's a lot of ways you could do it, but definitely look into the fields_for tag.

Comment: He doesn't have files association.

Comment: Yeah unfortunately this app was not created using a separate associated model that allows multiple files for each file type. Agreed that would have been ideal but thats not how the developer chose to go and I can't change it now

Comment: The part I am struggling with is replacing all the portions of code that reference the file field (in the code sample I included) with dynamically named variables that get created in a loop